# Why the ItemsSource is not updated in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

My window uses `MyUserControl` and passes to it a collection of items through `MyItemsProperty` property. `MyUserControl` converts the items to `MyClassBag` and adds the items to `WrappedItems` collection (OnMyItemsChanged->CollectionChanged->AddItem) which is bound to ItemsSource of `DataGrid`.

The problem is that ItemsSource is not updated (I set a brakepoint on `control.WrappedItems.Add(new MyClassBag { ... });` and it does get there).
But, if I put a button inside `MyUserControl` and add items (`WrappedItems.Add(new MyClassBag { ... });`) through button's click method the ItemsSource does get updated. What is the problem?

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =             
      DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems",
         typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>), 
         typeof(MyUserControl),
         new PropertyMetadata(
            new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(),
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyItemsChanged)
         )
      );

    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyItems>)GetValue(MyItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnMyItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        control = d as MyUserControl;
        var items = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<MyClass>;

        states.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
        AddItem(control, items);
    }

    private static void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = sender as ObservableCollection<MyClass>;

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            control.AddNewItem();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyClassBag> WrappedItems { get; set; }

    public void AddNewItem()
    {
        WrappedItems.Add(new MyClassBag { ... });
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewItem();
    }
}
```

**MyUserControl.XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WrappedItems ... />
<Button Click="Button_Click" />
```

**Window.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> ItemsForMyUserControl { get; set; }

    private void Load()
    {
         ItemsForMyUserControl.Add(new MyClass(...));
         ItemsForMyUserControl.Add(new MyClass(...));
    }
}
```

**Window.xaml**

```
<uc:MyUserControl MyItems="{Binding ItemsForMyUserControl}" />
```

Comment: After adding controls, databind the Grid again in code and see if that sort your problem. Just a quick tip until I try this over.

Comment: @voddy, what do you mean to databind the Grid again?

Comment: does your MyClassBag inherits INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: No, MyClassBag doesn't inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. Why should it? I don't change properties of MyClassBag. I just add items to collection

Comment: I noticed that if I replace DataGrid with ItemsControl the code above works. So why it doesn't work with `DataGrid`?

Comment: Ok. I am just thinking.. DataGrid.Columns is of course type of ObservableCollection. So may be, we are trying to bind it to the wrong  level.

Comment: @voddy, to explain the problem I a little bit simplified the code: when I call the method `AddNewItem` from `Button_Click` the ItemsSource is updated and I see the item in `DataGrid`. But when it's called from CollectionChanged (control.AddNewItem();) the item is does added to `WrappedItems` but I don't see it in DataGrid

Comment: Ya. I get it now. You can try to set dataContext of the grid after adding the control. eg: YourdataGrid.DataContext = WrappedItems;

Comment: @voddy, I tried `mygrid.DataContext = WrappedStates;` together with `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WrappedStates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Name="mygrid">` and it doesn't work

Comment: It looks like you're declaring "control" as a static field somewhere (not shown) and setting and then using it in different contexts that may not be getting the same instance but not enough code is shown to tell.

Comment: @JohnBowen, I've updated my code. I added also how `Window` passes the collection to `MyUserControl`. Please tell me if you need more code

Comment: You're still using an undeclared "control" variable in two of your static methods in MyUserControl (this can't compile as is). If in your actual code you have this declared as a static field it is being overwritten and is probably not the instance you think it is when it's being used later.

Comment: @JohnBowen, what do you mean an undeclared "control". In `OnMyItemsChanged` I get the reference to the control.

Comment: The line "control = d as MyUserControl;" is not valid unless a variable named "control" has been declared somewhere in scope, which it hasn't in your code. The same applies to "control.AddNewItem();"

Comment: @JohnBowen, to test that this is same control I've set a breakpoint in `Button_Click` and saw that it has all items that were added in `CollectionChanged`. So, I'm sure that the control `this` in `Button_Click` is the same control in `CollectionChanged`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem some time ago.

Please make the `MyClass` class inherit from `Freezable` class and everything may work. Please let me know if it helped.